# .net remoting close connection to server after call

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

I am very new to .NET remoting. We have an MVC website making call to a Windows application using TCP connection (.NET remoting). There is a timer running every 30 seconds which makes a call via TCP, but after it finishes, the connection still remains established. As a result, after a few days, the server is throwing an exception because all ports are used up. Then we have to restart the app pool to resolve the issue. I am not sure how can we close the port after use, so that we can use it again. We have a lot of users for the site.

Below is the client side code to register a channel

```
        bool Registered = false;

        foreach (IChannel ic in ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels)
        {
            if (ic.ChannelName == ChannelNameRemoting)
            {
                return ic;
            }
        }

        // Channel not found yet


        IDictionary channelConfig = new Hashtable();
        channelConfig["name"] = ChannelNameRemoting;
        channelConfig["secure"] = false;

        BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider defaultClientSink = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();

        if (remotingSinkProvider == null)
        {
            remotingSinkProvider = new CustomClientChannelSinkProvider();

            remotingSinkProvider.EncodingDecodingProviderEvent
                += new CustomClientChannelSinkProvider.EncodingDecodingProviderDelegate(remotingSinkProvider_EncodingDecodingProviderEvent);
        }

        defaultClientSink.Next = remotingSinkProvider;

        IChannel channel = new TcpChannel(channelConfig, defaultClientSink, null);

        if (!Registered)
        {
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

        }

        return channel;
```

Below call will create a connection to connect to the server in timer.

```
var connection = (testConnect)Activator.GetObject(
                                      typeof(testConnect),
                                      "tcp://" + _remotingUrl + ":" + _remotingPort + "/test/test4"
                              );

connection.FunctionCall();
```

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, in case you didn't realise, .net Remoting has been superseded by WCF, and only supported for backwards compatibility https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/migrating-from-net-remoting-to-wcf

Comment: Yes. We are aware of this but this is an old piece of code which creating problem. Thank you.

Comment: I presume you meant _server_ side code to register a channel?

Comment: You need to post the system.runtime.remoting section of the hosting application. Look for <wellknown> elements under the application element. You can change the mode to SingleCall and it will teardown the connection every time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to UnRegister you channel.
Please check the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c7a68c23-03dd-477c-86b8-8954a3220a9b/disconnecting-a-tcp-channel?forum=netfxremoting)

So ultimately we create the instance of `TcpChannel` and register it to channel service, and then finally return it to parent method, so that can use and can make the call.  in the file/class where you have method that return the channel instance should also have another method to unregister the tcp channel, and once you are done with the call, you need to call this new methd to unregister the channel, and that will close the connection.

```
public void UnregisterMyTcpChannel(TcpChannel yourChannelInstance)
{
   ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(yourChannelInstance);
}
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, the channel is only registered once when the user is log in and it stays registered until the user logs out. The connection is made via Activator.GetObject.

Comment: That shutdowns the entire remoting server.  A bit heavy-handed if there are legitimate connections

Comment: @MickyD `shutdown remote server`?? how a client can shutdown a server??

Comment: I said _"remoting server"_.  Secondly, why would client code call `UnregisterChannel`?

Comment: I understand.  but in remoting client and server are two separate things, and they run in there own boundary, client can connect to server, and request the call define in server, but how a client itself can close a server ? I dont think its possible. only code that running in server boundary can shutdown server, code running in client boundary can't shutdown server as per my knowledge.

Comment: You've misunderstood me.  `ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel` should only be performed from the context of the Remoting Server and doing not only closes all connections (heavy handed) but also prevents any further connections.  Thus the Remoting Server is no longer available to Remoting Clients wishing to use that particular channel

Comment: We cannot UnregisterChannel the channel because other clients are using it.